# Chrome extension Content Security Policy directive error

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm trying to make radio stream chrome extension but there is a problem. When I run my script in browser like normal JS+HTML+CSS it works, but when I try runing it like Chrome extension I get this error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
>   chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a
>   hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable
>   inline execution.

After that I added this to my manifest:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

But after that I was getting error message(error in manifest line with code above)

---

This is my manifest:

```
{
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "jquery.js", "jquery-ui.js", "plate.js" ]
        },

   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "Images/action-normal.png",
      "default_popup": "player.html",
      "default_title": ""
   },
   "description": "Chrome Player",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Radio Chrome Player",
   "permissions": [ "http://www.radio-station.com/" ],
   "version": "1.0"

   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"

}
```

This is the main html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script>$(function(){$("#radioplayere").plate({playlist: [{file:"http://RADIO_STATION_STREAM_URL/;"}], phpGetter: "http://hostingshoutcast.com/stream/plate/php/plate.php"});});</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="radioplayer">If you are seeing this then an error has occurred!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your problems are as follows:

1. Chrome CSP [forbids inline code](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution), and this is not subject to override. Your `'unsafe-eval'` does not address the issue, and `'unsafe-inline'` that would've helped [will be ignored](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-inline-script) by Chrome.

   You need to get rid of inline code:

   ```
   <script>$(function(){$("#radioplayere").plate({playlist: [{file:"http://RADIO_STATION_STREAM_URL/;"}], phpGetter: "http://hostingshoutcast.com/stream/plate/php/plate.php"});});</script>
   ```

   This needs to be moved in a js file.
2. There is a typo in your manifest.json, you forgot a comma:

   ```
   "version": "1.0",
   ```

   In general, using a [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/) can help you catch those errors.

Comment: Hi, tnx this solved half of my problem, now I can run it like extension but I'm getting this error:
 
`Refused to load the script 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?callback=jQuery17105420794193632901_13982…rtist=David+Craig+ft+Sting&track=Rise+and+Fall&format=json&_=1398287917991' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".`

And because of that I can't get song name.

Comment: @user3397388 Read carefully about the Content Security Policy. It explains how you need to modify it.

Comment: Not helpful.. and Xan, a link would be helpful

Comment: @ValentinoPereira A link to what? Documentation about CSP is linked in the answer (both links go to different sections of the same page), and it contains advice on how to deal with inline code and loading external code.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late to this, but based on OP's comments to Xan's answer, another component of solving the issue would be to adjust the AJAX call that is implied.

I was getting the same error and adjusted my API call to be:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

instead of:

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
```

(Solved the issue, granted, one will still need to remove any inline scripting.)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the reason is that I'm using an older version (such as v1.7) of jQuery that has **CSP** problems, choose a new version (v2.1.3).

Answer (score -1):

Adding CSP in manifest.json file removes the error. It worked for my react app.
I guess missing ' , ' is the issue for your code, otherwise add the below line and then try.

```
"csp": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self'"
```

[content security policy](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/manifest/content_security_policy.html)