# Can't run JavaScript lines from popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

When I try open the following page as a popup I encounter with the message:

> Refused to load the script 'http://allinternetfinance.com/LetMeKnow/jquery-1.11.2.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'
>
> index.html:4 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-anuyZ9J88P7xGyiuMhMfVwpc613qkiD1ZB3UusOLD6A='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."

the html is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://allinternetfinance.com/LetMeKnow/jquery-1.11.2.js";></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        window.location.replace("http://localhost:8080/MembershipApp/index.html");
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
```

all I get is little white square instead of the page Im trying to redirect it to.

Comment: are you running this from a google extension ? if not then it could be related to some XSS HTTP headers : [see](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers). `script-src 'self'` mean that you are only allowed to execute script from the same src than the current page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216884/chrome-extension-content-security-policy-directive-error

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things first:

- Download Jquery and load it from inside your extension folder, or don't use it at all.
- Move the content of the script tag to a .js file and reference it.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

Also, it seems like popups must contain extension files, instead use

`chrome.tabs.create({ url: "http://localhost:8080/MembershipApp/index.html"})`

Answer (score 0):

Please read up on script injection for chrome extensions.
[Programmatic Injection for Chrome Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi)

1. You likely do not have [cross-origin permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission) for extension
2. You have to "inject" the script or use a [manifest declaration](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration) before it is usable. This is due to headers and "same origin policy" for modern browsers as a security measure.

Lastly, make sure you inject the script into the newly created tab, or into an existing tab, **DO NOT** execute the script inside of the popup window itself or it will execute inside the popup box as if it was it's own window (Unless that's what you want.)

**EDIT:**
Ideally, you'll want to download the jquery script as mentioned by another poster, and host that inside of your extension. Make sure you declare the jquery library as a [Web Accessible Resource](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) though or you'll get another security error.

Hope this helps.

JRad The Bad