# How to get selected text in chrome extension development?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension which involves getting selected text of the current tab. Here is the html file that I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
                code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
            }, function(selection) {
                document.getElementById("output").value = selection[0];
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work, why? As followed is the error message from **Chrome App & Extension Developer Tool**, some of these error messages are cut with ellipses, sorry I haven't figured out how to view the full error messages here, **view details** only gives me the stack track, not the full error message.

[image]

Comment: You cannot have inline scripts in extension pages, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution). Move your code into a separate script file ("popup.js", for example) and reference it from your popup.html using a script tag. Also, not critical, but DIVs don't have a value property. Use a textarea element instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extension Content Security Policy directive error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216884/chrome-extension-content-security-policy-directive-error)

Comment: The pointed duplicate is correct _as a first step_, however, there aren't enough details here - what part of your extension are you showing? A popup? A background page?

Comment: True that. I did think about it, but the assumed the code is taken from [this post using a popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164474/chrome-extension-get-selected-text).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original approach was correct (and probably taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164474/chrome-extension-get-selected-text)).

It had 2 problems:

1. Inline scripts (`<script>...</script>`) [are not allowed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution); it's fixed by putting code in a separate file, say, `popup.js`.
2. You need permission to access a page for content script injection; in your particular case, there's a specific permission, [`"activeTab"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab), that does it in a transparent and painless way with no security warnings. When your extension is invoked (by clicking on the button), you are given access to the current tab.

With those fixed, your "direct" approach works.

By the way, to debug such problems in future, you need to [inspect the popup page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging#inspect-popup).

---

As for your own answer, you are over-complicating things a lot.

You don't need an Event page is this particular case; your popup can call `executeScript` and listen to messages. There are cases when you *do* need it, specifically when you can't guarantee that popup is open when content script sends messages; but here you can guarantee it.

Supposing you need the event page, consider *not* using `getBackgroundPage` to call a method in it - it tightly couples code; you can instead send a message. `sendResponse` can be used to pass the results back, [even asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20077854/934239).

Finally, your schema is confusing with respect to `content.js`. Only one copy of it executes, in a special context that is attached to the target page (and not in the extension context).

Answer (score 19):

As @Xan suggested, the method mentioned before (you can find it [here](https://searene.github.io/2015/12/09/get-selected-text-in-chrome/)) is overcomplicated. To get it to work, there are only two things to do:

1. Change `value` to `innerHTML` in `document.getElementById("output").value`
2. Add an `activeTab` permission in `manifest.json` file

Here is the complete source code, three files in total.

## manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "sample",
    "description": "A sample extension to get the selected text",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": { 
        "16": "img/icon16.png",
        "48": "img/icon48.png",
        "128": "img/icon128.png" 
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

## popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
    code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, function(selection) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = selection[0];
});
```

Comment: I shall upvote this for excellent explanation, but you _are_ overcomplicating things.

Comment: Hmm. No, I retract that. You are _horribly_ overcomplicating things.

Comment: @Xan Thank you for your suggestion, I've updated my answer.